# How do I collect data from a div to use in a form

Tags: forms, jquery

I must first admit that I am not super proficient at jQuery. I am trying to build a messaging system. I have a stream of messages that contain unique information divided into divs with unique identifiers. These divs also contain other information that I wish to pass to a form. In each div is a link that starts a function. That function is to launch an ajax request to get a form.

How do I dynamically generate these links to collect the data from it's parent div and insert it into the form I am requesting? Here is some of the code for the messages:

```
<div id="4000" class="message messages">
<a name="messagestamp_#"></a>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="messagetable">
<tr>
    <td valign="top" width="80" rowspan="3">
        <div class="usr">
            UsrName
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="message_data" valign="top" width="100%"> 
        <div class="message_header">
            <ul>
                <li class="ticker">...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
        <div class="tweet_content">
            <div class="tweet_text" class="">Some words will flow here. And here is another line. The standard carrige return will now cause a wrap to another line.
            </div>
        </div>  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="message_toolswrapper">  
        <div class="message_timestamp show">
            Aug 13th at 6:34am
        </div>
        <div class="message_tools hide">    
            <span class="message_social">
                <ul>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </span>     
            <span class="message_options">
                <a href="#" id="reply_link">reply</a> |
            </span>     
        </div>
        </div>  
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The data I wish to collect is the id in the initial div tag as well as the content div tag classed "usr". And the link I wish to use is the href "reply_link.

The link already does a number of things, such as change the visibility of a div and hide all others. I need it to also, pass this information to my form. It is currently using a .load Ajax method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var linkval = $("#reply_link").attr('href');
var userName = $('.usr').html();
var id = $('.messages').attr('id');
```

Comment: This allows me to collect the info... Fantastic. How do I then send this into the form loaded by ajax? So that when my user hits send on the reply form, this information is also sent and displayed in the form before being sent? Thanks a ton.